# TClientDataSet - SaveToStream throws Access violation

Tags: delphi, stream

I have a problem with saving data to stream with a ClientDataSet.

I put data in the ClientDataSet and try to:

```
...
var
strmBENU: TMemoryStream;


implementation    
...

TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.SaveToStream(strmBENU);
end;

...
```

Clicking Button1, here is what I get:

*Access violation at adress 0049CEB2 in module 'Project2.exe'. Reading address 00000000.*

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a NULL reference.  Have you instantiated `strmBENU`?

Comment: Nice, i instantiated it and now it says when i try to ClientDataSet2.LoadfromStream(strBENU)      
An exception has been thrown in project2.exe: EDatabaseError: 'ClientDataSet2: Missing Data-Provider or DataPackage.' Process stopped.

Comment: forgot to insert the Provider Name on the CDS2. but loading from stream and then opening CDS2 gives me no data in my TDBGrid2

Comment: failed due to some noob error not connecting the datasource to the DBGrid.

Question now it. how to get that over sockets... but that is another question already opend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244465/software-design-tier-2-application-with-clientdataset-and-sockets

Answer (score 3):

Probably the stream is not created. Try this:

```
TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  strmBENU: TMemoryStream;
begin
  strmBENU := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ClientDataSet1.SaveToStream(strmBENU);
    // do stuff with stream
  finally
    strmBENU.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: see comment on Mitch Wheats answer